# Why might Chrome return an incorrect MIME type error for one of my JS files when they are all served the same way?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mime-types

I'm getting an error reading one of my JavaScript files ("Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.") from Google Chrome.  The other three JS files that my page calls load just fine, and I'm confused about what is causing this problem since they are all marked up in exactly the same way (and each has a `"type=text/javascript"` attribute).  Safari and Firefox both have no problem reading all four JS files.  Can anyone give me a tip on how to troubleshoot this properly?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Without going any further, this error what it tells us is that we are sending JS code as **plain text** rather than sending the header as a script.

This is and happens because we define the tag as an attribute `<script type="text/javascript">`, when we should put `<script type="application/x-javascript">`.

**Incorrect example:**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>`

**Correct example:**

`<script type="application/x-javascript" src="js/utils.js"></ script>`

Then Google Chrome will understand it.

```
                                                                      Jordi. :)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your JavaScript files is not being sent with the correct `Content-type` header. The `type` attribute specified in the `script` tag won't have an effect here - it's the *script file*'s header that counts.

My guess would be it has a non-standard extension (e.g. `.php` or `.asp`) that causes your server to send a different MIME type that that for `.js` files.

Comment: The file in question has a .js extension.. Is the script file's header somehow altered by the server, and should I be looking at the server's settings?  The file in question is David Desandro's jQuery Masonry script, and I haven't changed it in any way.

Comment: @Sergio strange. Can you confirm the `Content-type` header sent for each script file e.g. using Firebug? Other than that, @dekomote's explanation makes sense, but I'd like to see some sources for that before I believe it

Comment: Well, strangely enough I'm having trouble in Firefox now too, although it was working fine all morning.  I'm pretty sure it is an issue with the server's settings, I'm now getting a 403 Forbidden error for that particular script file.  :P  Have to leave the computer for now, but thanks for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a webkit bug. I don't think you can troubleshoot this.

Comment: It works fine in Safari's webkit implementation...  But then, I'm not well-versed in how the implementations differ between the two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try using proper content type in the page which actually refer the script.

Something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and then start your HTML with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

PS: the magic is in the "strict" :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the file actually exists too. In FireFox it will report that it was loaded even when the file doesn't even exists.

[image]